# Modify an exisiting Excel via Apache POI and JavaFx

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi

I'm trying to write a little program. It shall rewrite an existing excel file and open it afterwards, after clicking a button. I want to use Apache POI for that.
So far the opening of the excel worked but no changes were made. After some trying i got a lot of errors, i can't tell where my mistakes are in the code.

Here is my Code of the Controller:

```
@FXML
    private TextField name;

public DarlehenController() {

    }

@FXML
    private void showExcel(ActionEvent e) throws Exception {

        String eingabeName = name.getText();
        try {
            FileInputStream fsIP = new FileInputStream(
                    new File("C:\\Users\\test.xls"));
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
            HSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            Cell cell = null;
            cell = worksheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(eingabeName);

            fsIP.close();
            FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File("C:\\Users\\test.xls"));
            wb.write(output_file);
            output_file.close();

            File excelFile = new File("C:\\Users\\test.xls");
            if (excelFile.exists()) {
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(excelFile);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported!");
                }
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("File is not exists!");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

The error occured after writing this to the Code, here should be the mistake:

```
  fsIP.close();
            FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File("C:\\Users\\test.xls"));
            wb.write(output_file);
            output_file.close();
```

This is my error report:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:144)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:113)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:301)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:413)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:394)
    at application.DarlehenController.showExcel(DarlehenController.java:139)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a debugger and not all classes have been reloaded property. Try to restart the program.

Comment: `Caused by: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document`: The header signature 0x00 is the one of an empty file. So your `File("C:\\Users\\test.xls")` is not a proper `Excel` file.

Comment: It definitely is an proper excel file, i even opened it with that code before.. 
started it several times now.. same problem